# Is there a way to keep a column immutable (insert-only) in jOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

The values for some columns are only meant to be inserted and never modified (effectively complex foreign keys but not mapped as such for various reasons). In JPA, this can be modeled via `@Column(updatable=false)`.

Is there a way to *systematically* (not manually) achieve this in jOOQ? I'm aware of the [read-only columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-readonly-columns/), but immutable (insert-only) columns don't seem to exist. Is that correct?

I know jOOQ is aware of JPA annotations in some contexts and since I do use the generated DAOs most of the time, I guess I *could* still use the annotation, but I'd prefer not to as I don't use JPA anywhere else in the project.

Comment: Have you considered doing this in a "BEFORE UPDATE" trigger on the table in plsql? (eg for oracle https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php)

Comment: @lance-java I have not, and that's a fair point. Thanks! But. I'd have to add `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` triggers (I don't want to outright reject an update, just ignore a specific column) and those are annoying to maintain, or have a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger which might not mesh well with `UPDATE ... RETURNING` (PostgreSQL) that I use everywhere or cause issues like e.g. [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)...

Comment: I've added an answer with a sample trigger

Comment: You can REVOKE the update permissions for this column, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Oracle trigger that could ignore updates to the "x" column on a table named "foo". Hopefully this is simple enough to convert to Postgres

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t_foo_bu
   BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
BEGIN 
   -- null safe equality check  
   IF NVL(new.x, chr(0)) != NVL(old.x, chr(0)) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ignoring attempted update of foo.x from ' || old.x || ' to ' || new.x || ' for id ' || new.id); 
      new.x = old.x;
   END;
END;
```

Comment: Ah, nice! I wasn't aware you could overwrite values in triggers like this! I'll try this out, seems like it solves my issue quite neatly.

Comment: Yes, since this is a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger you have a chance to intercept/change the values before the `UPDATE` occurs.

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for PostgreSQL and will never work. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html Please delete or update the answer

Comment: Correct, I updated the text to say it was Oracle syntax. Hopefully simple enough to convert to Postgres

Comment: @FrankHeikens To be fair, that is on me. I added the PostgreSQL tag later, as I was initially expecting a jOOQ-specific (and thus DB agnostic) solution. But all in all, the core idea stands. The syntax can be converted.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger by @lance-java is valid for Oracle but not for Postgres. Postgres requires a  function that *returns trigger* and a trigger definition invoking that function. However, the approach is appropriate; just replace the new value with the existing one (no reason to even look at the values). See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z6pCwS2o).

```
create or replace function make_x_immutable() 
   returns trigger 
   language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
   new.x = old.x;
   return new;
end; 
$$;

create trigger  foo_bur
    before update on foo
    for each row 
    execute function make_x_immutable() ;
```

**Note**. Older versions of Postgres may require *execute procedure ...* on the trigger definition.

Comment: Please note my answer was given before the OP added the Postgres tag to the question

Comment: @lance-java, understood, but necessary for OP to understand it will not work in Postgres. But I'll rephrase.

Comment: That's not correct. The OP stated on my answer "But all in all, the core idea stands. The syntax can be converted."

Answer (score 1):

### Readonly columns

As of jOOQ 3.19, there's only a general [`readonly` flag](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-readonly-columns/) that you can put on columns, not a more specific `insertonly` or `updateonly` flag. That would be a nice feature to have in future versions:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/16005

You can, however, [configure the above flag to apply only to `INSERT` or only to `UPDATE` statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/readonly-columns/), globally, or locally, on a per query basis. This will apply to all columns in the query, not just the ones you have in mind, which isn't really a problem for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, but it could be a problem for `MERGE`.

This approach affects both `UpdatableRecord` calls as well as queries written manually using the jOOQ DSL.

### RecordListener

If this is only about `UpdatableRecord` interactions, you can implement a [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/crud-record-listener/), which prevents the inclusion of certain columns in your `UPDATE` statements. This would affect all `UpdatableRecord.store()`, `UpdatableRecord.update()` calls, but not queries written manually.

### SQL transformation

You can write an `ExecuteListener` that checks and patches the [`Update.$set()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/QOM.Update.html#$set()) list very easily. Just check if the `Update.$table()` applies and then if `Update.$set()` contains a "forbidden" column:

In your [`ExecuteListener.renderStart()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html#renderStart(org.jooq.ExecuteContext)) implementation:

```java
class NoUpdates implements ExecuteListener {
    Set<Table<?>> tables = null;
    Set<Field<?>> fields = null;

    @Override
    public void renderStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        UnmodifiableMap<
            ? extends FieldOrRow, 
            ? extends FieldOrRowOrSelect> originalMap;

        if (ctx.query() instanceof QOM.Update<?> u
            && tables.contains(u.$table())
            && (originalMap = u.$set())
                   .keySet()
                   .stream()
                   .anyMatch(fields::contains)
        ) {
            var newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(originalMap);
            var it = newMap.keySet().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext())
                if (fields.contains(it.next()))
                    it.remove();

            if (originalMap.size() != newMap.size())
                ctx.query(u.$set(newMap));
        }
    }
}
```